# How to treat the byte value as int in java

Tags: java, string, hashcode

I am trying to do the hashcode calculation manually of string as it says the formula for String hashcode as " s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]", As below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = new String("A");

        double hc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            int iv = (byte) str1.charAt(i);
            hc = hc + Math.pow((iv * 31), (str1.length() - 1 - i));
        }

        System.out.println(hc);              // 1.0
        System.out.println(str1.hashCode()); // 65
    }
```

The value of 'hc' is 1.0 because java converts byte to int value as per rules.
but the answer i am looking for is 65.
How to copy byte value as it is to an int variable.

Comment: Hint: Ctrl-click or Cmd-click on `hashCode()` in your IDE, and that should lead you to its source code. You'll have the answer there. Nowhere does it say that characters are cast to bytes. Why do you do that?

Comment: Maybe you think Strings are made of bytes? They're not, they're made of `chars` which are 16 bits wide.

Comment: Instead of `String str1 = new String("A");` you should just do `String str1 = "A";`.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to code it manually, basically want to know "How to copy byte value as it is to an int variable.". I have not found it in source code. Thanks

Comment: @DodgyCodeException,I know that String are made of chars. ```String str1 = "A";``` this wont help, gives the same result as above

Comment: `int value = s.charAt(i);`. Your algorithm is just wrong. Look at the source code for the correct, simple algorithm.

Comment: Sorry I should have made clear that `String str1 = "A";` was just a suggestion for clearer and more efficient code, not an answer to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from far what i see u make mistake in function what i mean by that:

```
Math.pow((iv * 31), (str1.length() - 1 - i))
```

is equal => (65 * 31)^(1[str.lenght] - 1 - 0[i value])

what gives something like (65*31) ^ 0 what gives 1 but you are looking for expression 65 * (31 ^ 0) [in conclusion] so the function should looks like

```
Math.pow((31), (str1.length() - 1 - i)) * iv
```

what i guess gonna give 65